# Anyone please explain why the component code is not saving .Its showing Field Integrity Exception

Tags: lightning, aura, component

I am getting field integrity exception while saving the below code
[image]

Comment: Please copy your code into the question instead of showing a screenshot where the error message actually obscures the crucial part of the code that is throwing the error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Put '>' in the end of the row[image]